# how to integrate twitter bootstrap html css with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

Hello there thanks in advance!  I've done a front-end template using twitter bootstrap. Now I want to use it for one of my learning project "Mini Job Portal". FYI I'm new in CI and I've basic understanding on php. Now can u guys please tell me how can I integrate my coded html, css, js with CI project, also plz tell me what would be the folder structure and how to linked it up. It would be good if you provide a tutorial link.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I used CodeIgniter the main locations for these types of files were as follows:

CSS and JS would have their own folders in the main public directory (where the main index.php file for CodeIgniter lives).

HTML is a little different due to the MVC framework. You basically setup views and then render them from the controller. Usually it's easiest to create a head.php view file which contains all the links to scripts, css, site header, main menu, etc and then include that in all your page views (as these elements are unlikely to change all that often).

Of course the setup I've suggested will depend on the design of your website.